# Some tips for the convergence or divergence of this integral

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I was hoping someone could help me, on how to proceed with this integral, I have to define the values for which $\alpha\in{\mathbb{R}}$ converges

$$\int_0^1\sqrt{x}\sin\left(\sqrt{x}\right)e^{3\sqrt{x}}\left(\frac{x}{1-x^2}\right)^{\alpha-1}dx$$

I am completely lost on how to proceed to be honest so I was wondering if you guys could lend me a hand on this one

For starters I've tried the substitution $t=\sqrt{x}$ giving me the integral

$$\int_0^1t^2\sin\left(t\right)e^{3t}\left(\frac{t^2}{1-t^4}\right)^{\alpha-1}dt$$

and try to see how this function behaves as $x\to1$ but I am still lost on how to proceed from here, because I can't seem to find something with the limit that helps me move forward

I hope I have been clear enough, and I'm sorry if this isn't a legitimately question

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: You have to concentarte on the behavior of the integrand nearv $0$ and $1$. Near $0$ use the fact that $\sin \sqrt x $ behaves like $\sqrt x$ to see that what you need is integrability of $x^{\alpha}$ (near $0$). The condition for this is   $\alpha >-1$.

Near $1$ you need integrability of $(\frac 1 {1-x})^{\alpha-1}$  and this requires $\alpha < 2$. Hence, the requiered condition is $-1 <\alpha <2$.

Comment: I am sorry, but why do I need to see the behaviour near 0, isn't the function continuous in 0, and furthermore why can I just "forget" about the denominator?

Also but I don't understand why does the function behave as $(\frac{1}{1-x})^{\alpha-1}$  as  $x\to1$

Excuse me for my confusion and thanks for answering!!

Comment: @Ramirogenta Take note of the factor $x^{\alpha -1}$. If $\alpha $ is negative and $|\alpha|$ is large there would certainly be a problem in integrability near $0$.

Comment: @Ramirogenta Near $1$ all the factors except $(\frac 1 {1-x})^{\alpha -1}$ have finite  non-zero limits so they don't affect integrability.

Comment: Ohhh, I see what happens know for $x$ near $0$, thanks.

However I still can't see how the function behaves as $(\frac{1}{1-x})^{\alpha-1}$ instead of $(\frac{x}{1-x^2})$

Comment: $1-x^{2}=(1-x)(1+x)$ and $(\frac x {1+x})^{\alpha -1} \to 2^{1-\alpha}$ as $x \to 1$. @Ramirogenta